# Mouse hover hides background image of <ul> <li> tabs

Tags: html, css

I have simple **HTML** `<ul>` and `<li>` tabs with some **CSS** applied [on jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pq7LC/21/).

Basically, each tab has the format (please check the code linked above for more detail):

```
...
<li class="icons ...">
  <a href="#"></a>
<li>
...
```

As you saw in the code, the icon on each tab is actually the **background image** of each `<li>` element.

When the **mouse hovers** on a tab, I would like to also **change the background color or background image** of the `<a>` element. When I try to do this, **mouse hover** then **hides** the tab image (`<li>` background-image). How can I get rid of it?

**----------Another way to say my problem------------------------**

What I mean is I have already had a `background-image` for `<li>` element, then I also want to have a `background-image` for `<a>` element **which is contained by** `<li>`, but if I did so (that's have both `<li>` and `<a>` has `background-image` with also `:hover` `background-image`), the `background-image` of `<a>` will hide the `background-image` of `<li>`, how to get rid of this problem?

**-------------Please check @ hradac 's reply, he understands my question correctly---------**

Comment: Why are you using multiple accounts to ask questions?

Comment: Just put the background that is currently on `li` on `a` and viceversa.

Comment: I have read this question, and the answers, and the comments, and I still don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.  The answers below seem fine to me.  I don't see why you would want to have four backgrounds over a single element.  Could you explain that?

Comment: @ bozdoz, I think I did not explain my question clearly, that's why most of you think the solution has been given, but it is not. Please check @ hradac 's reply, he understands my question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Change the background-color of the LI containing your A instead.
That way your background-image won't be hidden by the A background-color.
See http://jsfiddle.net/Pq7LC/21/

Comment: I don't understand you, even your link is the same as that in my question which still has the problem I described. Can you please describe more accurate, or link with a working code? So that I can see what you mean

Comment: @ Simon, no, you don't get what my question is though you modification looks working, but not work in the way what I meat. What I mean is I have already had a background-image for <li> element, then I also want to have a background-image for <a> element which is contained by <li>, but if I did so, the background-image of <a> will hide the background-image of <li>, how to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Remove this part from your css:

```
a:hover
{
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #990000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ryZ4j/2/

Comment: No, please see my updates above, what I mean is background-image on both <li> and <a>, but <a> background image will hide <li> background-image, how to get rid of this. Not to remove the <a> background image

Comment: @ bozdoz, it is not, please check @hradac's reply, he understands my question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather you would like to have a background image in an `<li>` and a background image in an `<a>` contained in it. Your code does not have any background images for the contained `<a>` tags. All of your `:hover` switching happens on the `<li>` elements.

The problem seems to be a layering issue. When you apply a background color to the contained `<a>` tags you can no longer see the background image of the `<li>` it is on top of. The background images are still there, you just can't see them. I suggest changing the background color of the `<li>` on `:hover` and leaving the background color of the `<a>` on transparent. That way you can still see the `<li>` background image.

See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/vzxGr/1/

Is this more like what you were looking for?

Comment: You are the one understand what I mean. Thank you!, I will try your suggestion tomorrow, and response to you tomorrow! Glad to hear your reply!

Comment: @Leem Did this ever work for you? If so I would appreciate your accepting my answer. :)